# Creating arrays in for loops

Tags: php, for-loop

I'm starting with a csv variable of column names. This is then exploded into an array, then counted and tossed into a for loop that is supposed to create another array.

Every time I run it, it goes into this endless loop that just hammers away at my browser...until it dies. :(

Here is the code..

```
$columns = 'id, name, phone, blood_type';

$column_array = explode(',',$columns);  
$column_length = count($column_array);  

//loop through the column length, create post vars and set default  
for($i = 0; $i <= $column_length; $i++)  
{  
    $array[] = $iSortCol_.$i = $column_array[$i];
    //create the array iSortCol_1 => $column_array[1]...  
    //$array[] = 'iSortCol_'.$i = $column_array[0];  
}
```

What I would like to get out of all this is a new array that looks like so..

```
$goal = array(  
    "iSortCol_1" => "id",    
    "iSortCol_2" => "name",  
    "iSortCol_3" => "phone",  
    "iSortCol_4" => "blood_type"  
);
```

Comment: I swear I was indenting....Sorry

Comment: I would suggest printing the value of $column_length before entering the loop by using die($column_count) and looking at that value. Also, you're using the variable $column_array[0] which doesn't take advantage of the $i variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array[] = 'iSortCol_'.$i = $column_array[0];
```

I think it's because you're assigning the value of $column_array[0] to $i AND using it as the loop index. Use another variable to do that, otherwise it just goes on and on.

**EDIT** Tested and pasted output

Working code, just tested it on local

```
$columns = 'id, name, phone, blood_type';
$column_array = explode(',',$columns);  
$column_length = count($column_array);  
$array   = array();
for($i = 0; $i < $column_length; $i++)  
{  
    //create the array iSortCol_1 => $column_array[1]...  
    $array['iSortCol_'.$i] = $column_array[$i];  
}  

var_dump($array);
```

This will output

```
array
  'iSortCol_0' => string 'id' (length=2)
  'iSortCol_1' => string ' name' (length=5)
  'iSortCol_2' => string ' phone' (length=6)
  'iSortCol_3' => string ' blood_type' (length=11)
```

Is this not what you want?

Comment: You're not actually assigning to $i (or you shouldn't be). You're actually assigning to `'constantstring'.$i` which shouldn't be possible at all if not for PHP's magic. :)

Comment: Tried that... its still crashing.. The server is returning >>>Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 14 bytes)

Comment: @GolezTrol.. What should I be doing?

Comment: Fixed some weirdness in the code. just testing. Anyone remember the PHP equiv of jsfiddle?  **EDIT** - Nvm, I tested it, it works. Output pasted in answer

Comment: @GolezTrol That made me courios so I just tried it out, and yeah, php actually is doing magic. Calling the code like in the original post really changes the value of `$i` to `id`. Even tough it shouldnt if I understood the operator precedence correctly: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Answer (score 2):

Simply change

```
$array[] = 'iSortCol_'.$i = $column_array[0];
```

to

```
$array['iSortCol_'.$i] = $column_array[$i];
```

and the `<=` to `<` in your `for` loop, otherwise you will display a blank array value in your end result. Because you need to go up to *but not including* the length of `$column_array`.

Comment: Your Right... but A few people changes my code from $column_array[$i];   to $column_array[0];

Comment: @Peter: That will simply assign `id` (the 0 index value of your array) to your new array. You will need to increment the key, hence `$i`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to write:

```
$array['iSortCol_'.$i] = $column_array[0];
```

Comment: Tried that... its still crashing.. The server is returning >>>Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 14 bytes)

Comment: You must be doing something wrong or have other code that crashes. I copied your code and got the error too. Then I modified that line accoring to my advise. Now `var_dump($array)` returns array(5) { ["iSortCol_0"]=> string(2) "id" ["iSortCol_1"]=> string(2) "id" ["iSortCol_2"]=> string(2) "id" ["iSortCol_3"]=> string(2) "id" ["iSortCol_4"]=> string(2) "id" }

Comment: They all became `id`, because you (and I) are using `$column_array[0]` instead of `$column_array[$i]`. :D

Comment: I still need to use $i in $column_array.... Stop editing the code in my question!